# UIWebView Error in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I am getting this error in webview while loading this url : http://www.thumbzine.com/rssfeed.php?vol=104

"Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 UserInfo=0xde6ce0 "Frame load interrupted""

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
             [NSURL URLWithString:@"thumbzine.com/rssfeed.php?vol=104"]]];
```

What is this error due to ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Im having the same problem. Looks like its related with "feed://" content (vs "http:// content).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *urlText = [NSString stringWithString:@"http://www.thumbzine.com/rssfeed.php?vol=104"]; 
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlText]]];
```

Comment: I used the above code but still no success. I implemented the didFailLoadWithError delegate mehod , its giving "Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 UserInfo=0xd6eaf0 "Frame load interrupted" as error.